# Fedex Function ("getRates") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

Im not sure what happened but after we moved to production I noticed that Fedex doesn't work. Magento 1.9.2.4. Here is the latest log, please help

```
    2016-10-21T19:44:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
                (
                    [UserCredential] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => I1giRQJpoGVOaNO9
                            [Password] => yHIvxRuyFXgehdoUPD4xS2HNv
                        )

                )

        [ClientDetail] => Array
            (
                [AccountNumber] => 3--------5
                [MeterNumber] => 1-----1
            )

        [Version] => Array
            (
                [ServiceId] => crs
                [Major] => 10
                [Intermediate] => 0
                [Minor] => 0
            )

        [RequestedShipment] => Array
            (
                [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
                [ShipTimestamp] => 2016-10-21T19:44:22+00:00
                [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
                    (
                        [Amount] => 1151.25
                        [Currency] => USD
                    )

                [Shipper] => Array
                    (
                        [Address] => Array
                            (
                                [PostalCode] => 91402
                                [CountryCode] => US
                            )

                    )

                [Recipient] => Array
                    (
                        [Address] => Array
                            (
                                [PostalCode] => 90242
                                [CountryCode] => US
                                [Residential] => 
                            )

                    )

                [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                    (
                        [PaymentType] => SENDER
                        [Payor] => Array
                            (
                                [AccountNumber] => 3-------5
                                [CountryCode] => US
                            )

                    )

                [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                    (
                        [CustomsValue] => Array
                            (
                                [Amount] => 1151.25
                                [Currency] => USD
                            )

                    )

                [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
                [PackageCount] => 1
                [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
                [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Weight] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Value] => 13
                                        [Units] => LB
                                    )

                                [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                                [InsuredValue] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Amount] => 1151.25
                                        [Currency] => USD
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[result] => Array
    (
        [error] => Function ("getRates") is not a valid method for this service
        [code] => 0
    )

[__pid] => 24137
```

)

Comment: Any other exception or notice in log?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue as the OP and here is my answer on how we resolved the issue.

We recently upgrade to Magento 1.9.3 (from 1.9.2) as well as going from PHP 5.5 to PHP 7. We did it in two phases. The first phase was to upgrade Magento. That went without a hitch. The second phase was to take the server from PHP 5.5 to PHP 7.0. Since Magento at the time of this post does not support PHP 7.0, we used the Inchoo PHP7 compatibility extension. We tested both phases on a staging box prior to moving to production.

The issue `Function ("getRates") is not a valid method for this service` happened during the second phase for us. We did not experience this issue on the staging box. The staging box and the production box are very very similar however they are not identical. The solution for us was to change the following in the php.ini

```
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled
```

We changed it from 1 to 0 (which means to disabled it), and restart PHP. Fedex started to work again.

Depending on your server setup, you could temporary add it to your index.php (not recommended) to see if it will work as well.

The code for that is (add it right around line 37):

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```

Comment: thank you, we fixed it by updating magento and reconnecting with fedex